# Display uploaded images from JSF managed bean back to XHTML pages to preview

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I'm uploading images using `<p:fileUpload>` as follows.

```
<p:fileUpload mode="advanced"
              fileLimit="1"
              allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/"
              update="@this"
              fileUploadListener="#{bean.fileUploadListener}"/>
```

The listener method in the associated JSF managed bean.

```
private byte[] file; //Getter only

public void fileUploadListener(FileUploadEvent event) throws IOException {
    UploadedFile uploadedFile = event.getFile();
    file = IOUtils.toByteArray(uploadedFile.getInputstream());
}
```

How to display this uploaded image file on `<p:graphicImage>` directly from this JSF managed bean after it has been uploaded? It is just to prompt a user that the image being previewed is going to be uploaded.

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11506762/display-uploaded-image-in-jsf or here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded?lq=1

Comment: Do you still need help with that ? The second method (client side javascript) posted by Emil Kaminski will save you a lot of bandwidth and electricity, so money ;)

Comment: The image is to be displayed for a preview on another tab (`<p:tab>` of `<p:wizard>`). Uploading and previewing of an image is on separate tabs. Therefore, I need a session scoped managed bean to get hold of the image. The client side solution is unlikely to work.